# How to perform a YTD aggregation on data arranged in parent child hierarchies with unary operators?

Tags: parent-child, mdx, cumulative-sum, iccube

I am using a parent-child relationship for accounts in the OLAP database icCube. To include financial logic I make use of unary operators. In addition, I have set-up several account hiearchies using the many-2-many relationship and all is working very smoothly, except ....

when I want to apply time logic on the result, e.g. show the YTD value for April,30 2014 by:

`Aggregate(crossjoin ({[View].[View].[Periodiek]},PeriodsToDate([Tijd].[Kalender].[jaar],[Tijd].[Kalender].currentmember)))`

I get the message:

> Aggregate() : the aggregation 'unary-operator' is not supported (measure or calculated measure/member:[Measures].[bedrag])

Apparently, this is not the way to do this.

How can one achieve cumulative figures (periods-to-date) in this setting?

Comment: what is the full `mdx` script? `[Measures].[bedrag]` is not in the snippet you provided but is in the error message. Unary-operators are `+` or `-` or `*` which are not in the snippet you provided so I get the feeling that the error might be somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is most certainly in the measure `[Measures].[bedrag]`, which I suspect is the `defaultmember` of the `measures` dimension. Please post the code for that measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of icCube - 4.8.2 - does not support the Aggregate function for measures with Aggregation type 'unary operator'. See Aggregation function doc [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Aggregate.php).

The Aggregate function is a bit dodgy if you're using many-2-many relations as well as special measure aggregation types. For example :

```
     Aggregate( { [Account1], [Account2] }, [Measures].[Special] )
```

If [Special] is a measure with 'Sum' aggregation type and [Account1] and [Account2] have a many-2-many relation we would be counting twice the same 'shared' amount (aka same row is counted twice).

Other measures with aggregation types are just not supported to avoid getting unexpected results. This applies for aggregation types a Open / Close / Distinct Count.

The solution in your case is using the Sum function :

- [Sum](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Sum.php)( [CompactSet](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/CompactSet.php)( [PeriodsToDate](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/PeriodsToDate.php)([Tijd].[Kalender].[jaar],[Tijd].[Kalender].currentmember) ) , [View].[View].[Periodiek] )

Compact Set allows to compact to set in case you're using days or hours reducing the set. It's a perfomance booster.

If you want to handle properly m2m relations and special measure aggregation types you can use Categories in icCube, see here some [doc](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/howto/categories.php). Quickly, they allow to define dynamically a members as a set of tuples.

To properly support Aggregate we should add a new method, e.g. icAggregate, that works as using Categories. The Aggregate function it's a bit strange, for the time being we mimic a bit SSAS...

Answer (score 1):

To prove the comment of Sourav try changing your measure to the following:

```
Aggregate(
  {[View].[View].[Periodiek]}
  * PeriodsToDate([Tijd].[Kalender].[jaar],[Tijd].[Kalender].currentmember)
  , [Measures].[MEASURE_NOT_bedrag]    //<<replace with actual
  )
```

Do you still get the same error?

Comment: whytheq, the 'unary operator' aggregation type is not supported in the Aggregate function in icCube. See my answer..

Comment: @ic3 Thanks. The Aggregate function is prolific in our cubes and code. We use the MS stack and Pyramid - this function is supported throughout.

Comment: @ic3 fair comment: not sure!

Comment: after you can check with a measure with a distinct count aggregation type

Comment: @ic3 we don't use any parent-child hierarchies so not really possible for me to check

Comment: It's the same problem for any hierarchy with many-to-many relations or if you use a measure that is defined with a distinct count aggregation type (instead of the classical 'sum')

Comment: @ic3 ok - I can confirm then that distinct counts via aggregate work fine via Pyramid